# GIMP fill gif canvas background with image background

Tags: gimp, background, gif

Normally people would want to make the gif background transparent.

But how to fill all the cavas background with the "grey-like color" background of the image and apply to all 90+ layers? I have downloaded and included the "interleave layers" but unable to make it work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `interleave-layers` script requires that the stack of layers and the inserted layers all have the same size. So you need to:

1. Use `Image>Canvas size` to enlarge the animation canvas to the final size, and select `Resize layers`>`All layers`. You can position your layers in the bigger canvas at that point (`Center` button, or drag them in the preview widget).
2. Add a layer to the image (it will normally assume the size of the canvas), filled with the background color
3. Make that layer invisible
4. Use `Image>Interleave layers>Interleave layers (sprite mode)` with:

   - `Layer`: the background layer
   - `Opacity`: 100%
   - `Mode`: `Normal`
   - `Merge`: `Yes`

This creates a new image.

Note that if your layers have no alpha channel, and the background color in the toolbox swashes is already set to your grey-like color, then just the first step of all this (`Image>Canvas size`) will be necessary, since Gimp extends alpha-less layers with the background color.